# Unable to change simple WPF Grid Lines color

Tags: c#, wpf

Why does this does not work??????????
I just want to change the gridlines to red!! Simple enough but doesn't work!

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgBarGrid"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Red"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="Red"
              GridLinesVisibility="All"
              >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Have you tried in a clean, reproducible XAML with no other styles and triggers?

Comment: have you set the itemssource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried, add it a couple items and they lines are red, except Header. Are you trying to make the header lines red? If so:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>`
```

You can add this on your xaml.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The porblem was due to my datagrid table being empty. Noob mistake!